# Get soft navbar details in native Android GLES2 App

Tags: android, c++, user-interface, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm building the UI for a c++ OpenGLES 2 android application and I would like to place a bar with icons at the bottom of the screen. When running the app in an emulator, the soft navbar renders over the bar making it difficult to tap anything that would eventually be rendered inside of it:

[image]

I would like my OpenGLES application to reduce the height of the screen when the soft navbar is present. To be clear, I don't want to go into immersive mode. I want the soft navbar to always be visible if there is one, the app must just resize its render area.

How would I go about finding out whether a soft navbar is present and if it is, get its size?

Comment: It doesn't automatically go into immersive mode unless you make it.

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't want to go into immersive mode, I just want to find out if a soft navbar is present, and if it is, get it's size.